# Feeding Data into TextVectorization's adapt function with a Generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

The standard way as per the documentation for the usage of the adapt function

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import TextVectorization

# Example training data, of dtype `string`.
training_data = np.array([["This is the 1st sample."], ["And here's the 2nd sample."]])

# Create a TextVectorization layer instance. It can be configured to either
# return integer token indices, or a dense token representation (e.g. multi-hot
# or TF-IDF). The text standardization and text splitting algorithms are fully
# configurable.
vectorizer = TextVectorization(output_mode="int")

# Calling `adapt` on an array or dataset makes the layer generate a vocabulary
# index for the data, which can then be reused when seeing new data.
vectorizer.adapt(training_data)
```

I wanted to know if there was anyway we can use a Keras Generator (like text_dataset_from_directory) or any other data generator to feed large data into adapt. For large textual data we are facing OOM errors while using the adapt function.

Comment: Did you find an answer?